# Reading and splitting a .raw file for data processing

Tags: python, file

Basically I have data from a mechanical test in the output format .raw and I want to access it in Python.

The file needs to be splitted using delimiter ";" so it contains 13 columns.
By doing this the idea is to index and pullout the desired information, which in my case is the "Extension mm" and "Load N" values as arrays in row 41 in order to create plot.

I have never worked with .raw files and I dont know what to do.

The file can be downloaded here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0GJeyFBNd4FNEp0elhIWGpWWWM/view?usp=sharing

Hope somebody can help me out there!

Answer (score 1):

Your file looks basically like a .tsv with 40 lines to skip. Could you try this ?

```
import csv

#export your file.raw to tsv
with open('TST0002.raw') as infile, open('new.tsv', 'w') as outfile:
    lines = infile.readlines()[40:]
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Or if you want to make directly some data analysis on your two columns :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TST0002.raw", sep="\t", skiprows=40, usecols=['Extension mm', 'Load N'])

print(df)
```

output:

```
   Extension mm       Load N
0       -118.284    0.1365034
1       -117.779  -0.08668576
2       -117.274   -0.1142517
3       -116.773   -0.1092401
4       -116.271   -0.1144083
5        -11.577   -0.1314806
6       -115.269  -0.03609632
7       -114.768  -0.06334914
....
```

Comment: But why does it make the last many values in Load N with two dots? 
Like the very last line: 
853      310.378   -8.992.958

This is causing me trouble as i want to define each column as arrays containing integers and not strings which is another problem.

Comment: Also as you can see in your own output, the values in Extension does not correspond to the actual values. Somehow the code transforms 11.8284 to 118.284. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I'm surprised. If you open your file with a text editor, you could see that the firts value of `Extension mm` is  -118.284. For the rest, the values appear exactly as in the file. Pandas has a function that allows you to change the type of a column (for example `df['Load N'] = df['Load N'].astype(int)`). But it will not be so simple with these values. Maybe the subject for another question.

Comment: I just checked it myself and im surprised too! Its not suppose to be like that.. however if you use another similar file which has the right values:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0GJeyFBNd4FUmNzMktkd3F5ZGM

The code doesn't go through? It says "Load N" and "Extension mm" not in the list.

Comment: The actual file type is semi collon separated as link above (i have 25+ files). I mustve somehow somewhere without knowing edited the TST0002.raw by a mistake before handing it over to you.

Comment: Because in your new file, values are not separated by a tabulation `\t` but by a semi-colon. Try changing `sep="\t"` by `sep=";"` in `df = pd.read_csv()`

Comment: I fixed it! I just put in delimiter=";" and deleted sep="\t" from the original code :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the raw file into csv file then use the csv module remember to set the delimeter=' ' otherwise by default it take comma as delimeter

`import csv
 with open('TST0002.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:   //this will read each row line by line
       print (row[0])  //you can use row[0] to get first element of that row.`

Comment: can use the row[2] to get the Extension values and row[3] to get the Load N values